# Obtain 2nd Character in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to create a loop function whereby if the 2nd character of each word in a sentence = 'R', then it will be printed out.

```
st = 'Print only the words'

for word in st.split():
    if word[1] == 'r':
        print(word)
```

I keep getting the error string index is out of range.

Comment: Works for me. You sure this is the exact example? No input data with 1-letter words like `'a'`?

Comment: It works for me too.

Comment: Either catch the exception or check the string length.

Comment: @schwobaseggl nope this is just a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve. I think I made a mistake in the qn somewhere! Thanks!

Comment: in question statement you mentions `R` and in code you are using `r` . is your 2nd character is case sensitive ?

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly filter out words with `len(word) < 2`, that should solve your `IndexError` problem:

```
st = 'Print only a word with at least two letters that has r in index 2'

for word in st.split():
    if len(word) > 1 and word[1] == 'r':
        print(word)
# 'Print'
```

Answer (score 1):

The index is out of range if the word only has one letter.

```
st = 'Print only a word, orange'

for word in st.split():
    if len(word) > 1:
        if word[1] == 'r':
            print(word)
```

Comment: My answer and andrew_reece's answer are identical in operation. He answered four minutes before me and therefore should get the credit.  I am leaving my answer open, since splitting the if may be easier to read for new users to python.

Answer (score 0):

How about using regexp ?

```
import re
re.findall(r'\b(.r.*?)\b',"Print the string or trim the string your lucky dry day")
```

> ['Print', 'or', 'trim', 'dry']